# How to fix TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe `df`:

```
Id    Version  Time
110   9016     NaN
110   9016     NaN
110   9016     NaN
110   9016     2019-10-18 14:19:05.180
```

When I run this query:

```
df.query('Time.isna()').head()
```

..I get this error:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Why does it happen and how to fix it? May it be related to the version of pandas and Python? I use Pandas '0.25.3' and Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter `engine='python'` here, because passed pandas function `isna` which cannot work with `numexpr` engine.  More info in docs for [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

> **engine** : string or None, default ‘numexpr’, {‘python’, ‘numexpr’}
>
> The engine used to evaluate the expression. Supported engines are
>
> **None** : tries to use numexpr, falls back to python
>
> **'numexpr'**: This default engine evaluates pandas objects using
>               numexpr for large speed ups in complex expressions with large frames.
>
> **'python'**: Performs operations as if you had eval’d in top
>               level python. This engine is generally not that useful.
>
> More backends may be available in the future.

---

```
df1 = df.query('Time.isna()', engine='python').head()
print (df1)
    Id  Version Time
0  110     9016  NaN
1  110     9016  NaN
2  110     9016  NaN
```

Or trick `NaN != NaN`:

```
df1 = df.query('Time != Time').head()
print (df1)
    Id  Version Time
0  110     9016  NaN
1  110     9016  NaN
2  110     9016  NaN
```

Comment: Could you please explane why do I get this error? Actually, I only get it in my laptop. When I run the code in the cloud, this line works fine...

Comment: @Fluxy - Not sure if something with pandas version, tested in pandas 0.25.1 and raise same error like in question.